# Prevent authenticated user to view other users profile on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I want to use Laravel 5 `AuthServiceProvider` to prevent logged in user to view other users profile. I'm using route like this `user/1`. How can I compare if the logged in user ID is match with the ID in the URL. If not then can't proceed.

Here's the following code I'm trying in my `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
$gate->define('view-profile', function($user, $id) {
    return Auth::user()->id === $id;
});
```

However, the above code doesn't work as I can't pass the correct ID from the URL. Can anyone please help?

Here's the code I've in my controller:

```
if (Gate::denies('view-post', [Auth::user()->id, (int) $id])) {
        return abort(403);
    } else {
        return 'success';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to let all of you know that I've figured it out myself using `Gate::forUser()` method. Here's the relevant code which I hope anyone may find helpful:

In `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
$gate->define('view-post', function($user, $id) {
    return $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

In your particular `Controller`:

```
$user = Auth::user();

if(Gate::forUser($user)->allows('view-post', $id)) {
    return 'true';
}

return abort(403, trans('Sorry, not sorry!'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you route user controller with user, then user/1 will route the user controller show function, and in show function you can check your authentication user with id:

```
Function show ($id)
{
if (  Auth::user()->id == $id) {
//your code here
}

}
```

Comment: That would work. However, I wanted to use the `AuthServiceProvider` as this has designed to perform this kind of action.